# enable textbox with removeattr and want to disable again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to enable all textbox if a condition is matched. There is a drop-down containing YES/NO as an option. If yes is selected then I want to disable some textbox again but it's not working. I used this code to enable all textbox:

```
$(':input').removeAttr('disabled');
```

After that, i used this code if Yes is selected from the drop-down.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var n = $("#pharmacy_pur").val();
    if(n == "YES")
    {
         $('#pharmacy_amount').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
```

But it's not working. Anyone suggest me how to solve this problem. where i want to enable all textbox and if a dropdown option(YES) is selected then disable some of them. Here is html part:

```
<select name="pharmacy_pur" ID="pharmacy_pur">
 <option value="YES"<?php echo $r1 == "YES" ? " selected" : ""?>>YES</option>
<option value="NO"<?php echo $r1 == "NO" ? " selected" : "";?>>NO</option>
                                </select>
<input type="text" name="pharmacy_amount" ID="pharmacy_amount"/>
```

PHP Code :

```
$qu="select * from `scan_1` where P_no='1'";
$res=mysqli_query($con,$qu);
if(!$res || mysqli_num_rows($res)==0)
{
echo '<script>alert("Invalid:");</script>';
} 
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
$r1=$row["Pharmacy_purchase"];
```

Comment: Add your `html` too.

Comment: Use `prop` instead of `attr`.... `$('#pharmacy_amount').prop("disabled", true);` for disabling

Comment: Is YES/NO `text` or the `value`?

Comment: I added my html code. Please suggest some solution

Comment: how do u check the value if it is YES or NO at edit time? it is possible is it using PHP or something else? can u please provide edit code as you need this functionality on edit time.

Comment: i added php code also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You want to make textbox enable and disable at the same time then place loop inside your you enable js code like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var n = '<?php echo $pr; ?>';
var r1='<?php echo $r5;?>';
if(n == "1")
{
    $(':input').removeAttr('readonly');
    $(':input').prop('disabled', false);
    if(r1=="NO")
    {
        $('#pharmacy_amount').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `prop` instead of `attr` to update DOM properties like `disabled`, `checked`, etc.

Replace

```
$(':input').removeAttr('disabled');
```

with

```
$(':input').prop('disabled', false);
```

And

```
if(n == "YES")
{
         $('#pharmacy_amount').attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

With

```
$('#pharmacy_amount').prop("disabled", ( n == "YES") );
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var n = $("#pharmacy_pur").val();
  $(':input').removeAttr('disabled');

  $("#pharmacy_pur").change(function() {
    var n = $(this).val();
    $('#pharmacy_amount').prop("disabled", (n == "YES"));
  });

  $("#pharmacy_pur").change();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="pharmacy_pur" ID="pharmacy_pur">
   <option value="YES" class="1">YES</option>
   <option value="NO" class="1">NO</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="pharmacy_amount" ID="pharmacy_amount" />
```

Comment: Yes it is working but what if Yes is already selected. I mean if i use this code in edit page and that page having YES in dropdown then it is not disable them

Comment: @Shalini Check the demo

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#pharmacy_pur').on('change', function() {
    var n = $("#pharmacy_pur option:selected").text();
    if (n == "YES") {
      $('#pharmacy_amount').prop("disabled", true);
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="pharmacy_pur">
<option value="">--select--</option>
<option value="YES">YES</option>
<option value="NO">NO</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="text" id="pharmacy_amount">
```

Comment: Yes it is working but what if Yes is already selected. I mean if i use this  code in edit page and that page having YES in dropdown and it is not disable them.